# Type Error when assiging string to variable in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am running the following command and receiving the following error:

```
| ?- list('A', List).
uncaught exception: error(type_error(evaluable,'A'/0),(is)/2)
```

This is the predicate where I believe the error is coming from. I assume it has to do with "Grade is 'A'. but I am not sure what exactly is wrong.

file1.pl

```
grade(First, Last, Grade) :-
   student(StudentType, First, Last, Exam1, Exam2, Exam3),
   StudentType = 'std',
   ((Exam1 + Exam2 + Exam3) / 3)>=90,
   Grade is 'A'.
```

Here are the other 2 files associated with the program:

file2.pl

```
list(Grade, List) :-
   findall([X, Y, Z], (grade(X, Y, Z), Z=:=Grade), List).
```

file3.pl

```
student('std', 'firstName', 'lastName', 100, 100, 90).
```

Comment: `s/Grade is 'A'/Grade = 'A'/` but note that your program only grades As, or fails.

Comment: @false if I change the 'is' to an '=' the error persists, but changes the (is) to (=:=) in the error message.

Comment: `s/Z=:=Grade/Z=Grade/`

Comment: Ahh that was it thank you!